# Strange Apache2::Cookie error under Strawberry Perl and mod_perl2

Tags: perl, cookies, apache2, mod-perl2, strawberry-perl

I have a set of scripts that run under ActivePerl 5.10.  However, under Strawberry Perl 5.10, I get a strange error message:

```
Can't locate object method "cookie_class" via package "MyCookie" (perhaps you forgot to load "MyCookie"?) at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/Apache2/Cookie.pm line 41.
```

However, `MyCookie` is the name of the cookie itself, not any Perl package.

If I comment out line 41 of Cookie.pm, the script runs, but I cannot successfully get or set cookies anymore.

The error message seems somewhat correct in that I can't find `cookie_class` either (except where it's mentioned in the POD files.)  That said, the same is true for my ActivePerl installation.

I think it's in `C:\strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\APR\Request\Request.dll`--how come it can't find it under Strawberry, but can under ActivePerl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to use the 2.X scheme like so:

```
my $j = Apache2::Cookie::Jar->new($r);
my $cookie = $j->cookies("MyCookie"); # works!  go figure...
```

Rather than the old method:

```
local our %cookies = Apache2::Cookie->fetch($r); # error was happening here
local our $cookie = $cookies{"MyCookie"};
```

(For some reason this seemed to fix it.)

Comment: Bizarre that the old school `fetch` worked with ActivePerl but not Strawberry. `Apache2::Cookie::Jar` works and is, I suppose, the proper way so congrats on sorting this out.

Comment: It is bizarre--and now I'm having problems with Apache2::Request::param that are equally bizarre, but I think I'm already doing it "the proper way" there.  Anyway, thanks for the confirmation and props for helping me so much.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you possibly mixing the apreq DLLs between the Strawberry and ActivePerl versions? Or mixing apreq-1 and apreq-2 DLLs somehow?

The area around the offending `cookie_class` call is just this:

```
my $jar = $req->jar or return;
$jar->cookie_class(__PACKAGE__);
return $jar->get(shift) if @_;
```

The `cookie_class` method does come from `Request.dll` and `$req` is type checked before `jar()` is called.

Comment: Not that I can see.  I followed the directions at http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/perl-modperl/201007.mbox/%3CAANLkTimP1oCDwBU2RZ2hfK4nMorZ-SoZlJ_ennx8JKTT@mail.gmail.com%3E and they have it install mod_perl2 from KMX's Strawberry-specific build.

Comment: What do you get when you call "$r->jar" yourself? Do you get an object? A scalar? Something that has a "cookie_class()" method?

Comment: I get `Can't locate object method "jar" via package "Apache2::RequestRec"`.

Comment: And if you say `my $req = APR::Request::Apache2->handle($r); $req->jar;`? I'm just walking through Apache2::Cookie::fetch line by line BTW, hopefully something will come up.

Comment: (Oddly, `$req->isa("APR::Request")` returns `1`, so the code you suggested, i.e. calling `handle`, shouldn't get executed in `fetch` 'normally'...)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, you or someone else is passing a string to a function that expects an object. Your best first step in debugging would be to load [Carp::Always](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Carp%3a%3aAlways) so that you can get a backtrace and find out what's really happening.

Comment: I did a stack trace.  But what's really happening is the same thing that's always been really happening: `%cookies = Apache2::Cookie->fetch($r)` where `$r` is an `Apache2::RequestRec` object.  The same code works fine under ActivePerl with no changes.   Also, at the point in the code at which it crashes, `MyCookie` is not checked for yet (not that it's passed to `fetch()` anyway), so I'm assuming it's getting this from the browser's actual cookie.

Comment: I deleted the browser's cookie, and sure enough, it no longer errors out.  However, now it no longer successfully sets the cookie, either.